# "Hunt deer with bows, with snares: rabbits," or referencing a verb from a previous clause

Tags: grammar-choice, translation-check, sentence-translation, english-to-latin-translation

I've been trying to translate the following phrase into Latin:

> Hunt deer with bows, with snares: rabbits.

With my limited grasp of Latin, I have come to this result:

> ```
> Vēnāre cervas arcubus, dēcipulīs leporēs 
> [<imp> <acc>  <abl> ]<<[<abl>    <acc> ]
> hunt   deer   bow    , snare     rabbit
> ```

I've mainly used [Wikipedia: Latin declensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_declension#Meanings_and_functions_of_the_various_cases) to decide which form to use, [Wordhippo](http://www.wordhippo.com/) and [Google translate](https://translate.google.com/) to decide which words to use, and [Wiktionary](https://www.wiktionary.org/) to find the proper declensions and conjugations of the words.

Now my question is, is it okay and proper form, and is it clear what is meant if the verb is implicitly reused by tacking on another clause without a predicate, or is that more of a Germanic thing?

Comment: (1) _decipulum_ / _decipula_ is a snare in a metaphysical sense, I think seldom used for the physical device used for catching either hare (_lepus_) or rabbit (_cuniculus_). (2) Why the fem. _cervas_, when the masc. includes both genders? (3) And a bit too pedantic, maybe, but isn't it the _sagitta_ that brings down the prey, not the _arcus_? But yes, the translation with these provisos is perfectly good.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your translation is excellent Latin.
The chiasm and ellipsis are very natural and good style.
The only thing I might change is the location of the imperative.
This change is optional.
I would put it at the very end:

> *Cervas arcubus, decipulis lepores venare.*

With small changes the phrase can also be turned into a pentameter line:

> *Cervam agita arcubus et decipulis lepores.*
> or perhaps
> *Cerva arcu capitur, decipulo lepores.*

I prefer the second one, but I will leave them both in case they are of interest to someone.
Since pentameter is rarely seen alone, this should probably be completed into an elegiac couplet.
For example (with prose translation):

> *Apte sic animal varium varie capiatur:*
> *Cerva arcu capitur, decipulo lepores.*
>
> Varying animals should be captured in various ways like this:
> A deer is caught with a bow, rabbits with snares.

The other option would have been "Hunt deer with bows and rabbits with snares." for the second line.